# Find correct column in Sheet even if Form fields change. Dynamically map Sheet column to correct data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var fRes1 = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

   function sendEmail() 
  {    
    var emailManager = ""; 
    var emailQuality = "";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];    
    var Row = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]; //Last Row
    var message = "";
    var subject = Row[2]; //Subject is on column 3

    for(var i in headers) 
    if(Row[i] !== "")
    {  
        message += headers[i] + Row[i] + "/n/n"; // Headers and Last Row will be the message
    }
    // Improvement Suggestion
    if(Row[2] === 'Improvement suggestion')
    {
    emailManager = Row[10];  //column where the header is called "Manager Email"       
    } 

    // Incident
    else if(Row[2] === 'Incident')
    {
      emailManager = Row[21];   //column where the header is called "Who should be informed?"

      if(Row[11] === "Option1")  // 
      {
       emailQuality = "emailaddress1@address.com"; 
      }

      else if (Row[11] === "Option2")
      {
       emailQuality = "emailaddress1@address.com"; 
      }
    }

    // Send the email
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailQuality + "" + emailManager, subject, message);

  }

  sendEmail();
}
```

Is there a more general way of extracting information from the spreadsheet to which the form submits the information?

Instead of using numbers like:

```
emailManager = Row[10];
subject  = Row[2];
if(Row[11] === "Option1")
```

Because if someone changes the form, new columns will be added or removed and then I will have to use another number.
Is there a more general way of knowing every time which column contains which options?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods each with their own level of complexity and utility. all of them allow the column to be anywhere so expansion of the form is possible.

### indexOf

If you don't do this a lot in your code you can access the value for row `r` by using

```
var resultT = a[r][a[0].indexOf("Col2")] // Access "Col2" of row r
```

### Index object

If you do this more often and want to avoid the index of (which may also get very expensive computationally) you can create an Object containing the header names and column info:

```
  var I = {}; // Indexing object

  for (var i = 0; i < a[0].length; i++) { // Assign indices to headers
    I[a[0][i]] = i; 
  }

  var result = a[r][I["Col2"]] // Access "Col2" of row r
```

Or in your case

```
subject  = Row[2];
var result = subject[I["Option1"]];
```

### Table Object

The most easy to use option but must cumbersome to set up is expanding on the Index object and just appends, instead of the index column the element of the transposed data array.

```
var table = {}
  for (var row = 0; row < a.length; row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < a[row].length; col++) {
      if (row == 0) {
        table[a[0][col]] = [];
      } else {
        table[a[0][col]].push(a[row][col]); 
      }
    }
  }

var result = table["Col2"][r-1];
```

You now have an object with column headers, each containing an array of that column (please not that this shifts the index as the header is not counted as a row anymore)
This requires us to access every element at least once and is a lot of work to perform. It's only worth it if you are going to access those elements a lot.
Personally I'd recommend Option 2.